# Checks the primality of consecutive odd integers in a specified range

Tags: algorithm, scheme

The following program finds the smallest integral divisor (greater than `1`) of a given number `n`. It does this in a straightforward way, by testing `n` for divisibility by successive integers starting with `2`.

`n` is prime if and only if `n` is its own smallest divisor.

```
(define (square x) (* x x))

(define (divisible? a b)
  (= (remainder a b) 0))

(define (find-divisor n test)
  (cond ((> (square test) n) n)
        ((divisible? n test) test)
        (else (find-divisor n (+ test 1)))))

(define (smallest-divisor n)
  (find-divisor n 2))

(define (prime? n)
  (= (smallest-divisor n) n))
```

How to write a procedure that checks the primality of consecutive odd integers in a specified range?

```
(define (search_for_primes from to)
   (cond ((> from to) false)
         ((prime? from) (display from))
         (else (search_for_primes (+ 1 from) to))))
```

My solution just write `1` to the output.

Comment: This may be useful: http://community.schemewiki.org/?sieve-of-eratosthenes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `cond` will stop at the *first* match and execute the corresponding expressions only. So if you execute `(search_for_primes 1 xxx)`, 1 is *erroneously* identified as a prime and the procedure stops there.

What you want is something like

```
(define (search_for_primes from to)
  (unless (> from to)
    (when (prime? from)
      (display from)
      (display " "))
    (search_for_primes (+ 1 from) to)))
```

where the recursion is done regardless of whether you found a prime or not.

Testing:

```
> (search_for_primes 2 100)
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

Comment: I need to add additional check for `2` yes? its not a prime number

Comment: 2 is a prime number, but 1 is not. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number.

Comment: For example, change `prime?` to `(define (prime? n) (and (> n 1) (= (smallest-divisor n) n)))`

Comment: How to find the three smallest primes larger than 1000 by using your procedure?

Comment: Add a parameter to the procedure and decrement it during the recursive call *only* if a prime was found.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely start with doing an efficient sieve (like the sieve of Eratosthenes) over the range to efficiently catch multiples of small primes.  If your numbers are small, just doing that up to `sqrt(n)` is good enough.  (This is good enough for, for example, Project Euler problems.)

If your range is small and numbers large, use that to just get "likely primes", then use your favorite primality test (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test for some options) on each one.

If your range is large and your numbers are large...you've got problems. :-)

Comment: ok, suppose my function `prime?` works log(n) time. How to fix my problem?